# Filtering join table in has_many :through in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have the following models in which I join the Language and Products table via the Translation table using the Rails has_many :through paradigm:

```
class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :translations
  has_many :products, :through => :translations
end

class Translation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :language
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Basehas_many :translations
  has_many :translations
  has_many :languages, :through => :translations
end
```

I want to find the English Language Translation for a particular Product.

I can list the associated Languages and Translations:

```
prod = Product.find(4)
en = Language.find(:first, :conditions => { :lang_code => 'en' })

puts prod.translations
puts prod.languages
```

This prints:

```
#<Translation:0x11022a4>
#<Translation:0x1102114>
#<Language:0x602070>
#<Language:0x602020>
```

(There is an English and French translation for this product.)

How can I get the Translation for `prod` corresponding to the `en` Language?

If that doesn't make sense, here is the equivalent SQL:

`SELECT t.* FROM products p, translations t, languages l WHERE l.id = t.language_id AND p.id = t.product_id AND l.lang_code = 'en';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need something along this:

```
product = Product.find(4)
translation = product.translations.find(:first,:joins=>:languages, :conditions=>{:language=>{:lang_code=>'en'}})
```

The code will produce a join of Translations with Languages and filter accordingly your lang_code.

If the brackets confuse you a bit (I know sometimes they do) you could also do something like this:

```
translation = product.translations.find(:first,:joins=>:languages, :conditions=>["languages.lang_code like ?",'en'])
```

That last bit should produce the same SQL query, joining Translations with Language and then filtering by it's lang_code.

Comment: Thanks, this works.  I got an error with your second code snippet until I made language plural: :conditions=>{:languages=>{:lang_code=>'en'}}

Answer (score 0):

Yaraher's answer works, although I found a simpler way to accomplish the same thing:

```
t = Translation.find(:first, 
                     :conditions => { :product_id => prod.id, 
                                      :language_id => lang.id })
```

Comment: Good to know I've been of some help! Take notice that for this one to work you'd need to know the Product.id AND the Language.id. If you already have them, no issue then. If not, you'd need an extra query for getting the Language.id where on your original question you'd only need one and send it the lang_code.